# (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new[] { parms }); throws an MissingMethodException

Tags: .net, generics, reflection, c#-3.0

I have a very simple generic constructor method:

```
public T Instance<T, TT>(TT parms) where T : class
{
    return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new[] { parms });
}
```

When I call the method like:

```
Instance<MyClass, string>("SomeStringValue").Customers.Where(x => x.Id == Id).Select(p => blah..blah...blah;
```

I get a 'System.MissingMethodException: Constructor on type 'MyClass' not found.
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture...'

I have tried adding bindingflags etc. but without any luck.

I am basically trying to instantiate an object with arguments.
I can without any problems explicitly declare the object:

```
var myObj = new MyClass("SomeStringValue");
```

But I need to make use of my generic constructor.

Can anyone clarify what I am missing?

*EDIT*
A complete program (simplified).

```
public abstract class A 
{
    public T Instance<T, TT>(TT parms) where T : class
    {
       return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new[] { parms });
    }
}

public class B 
{
    public B(string someValue)
    {
        var myValue = someValue;
    }
}

public class C
{
  public void DoStuff()
  {
     var x = Instance<B, string>("SomeStringValue");
  }
}
```

Is what I am trying to do.

Comment: Is the constructor public? A short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem would make this easier to help you with.

Comment: Your `Instance` method will not compile. `params` is a keyword.

Comment: Yes the constructor is public. Sorry param is actually parm. I will edit it right away.

Comment: Can you check which overload of the `CreateInstance` method is invoked? Note that [`CreateInstance(Type, params object[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d.aspx) is declared with the `params` keyword: Therefore, I *suppose* that the compiler thinks that your `TT[]` is the first parameter, so it's looking for a constructor of `B` that takes a `string[]` rather than one `string`.

Comment: It is actually working now...just needed to add object[].

return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[] { parms });

Is that the way to do it? I was hoping to make use of my TT and actually avoid using object.

Comment: The `Activator.CreateInstance` overload expects an `Object[]`; if one constrains `TT` to a class type, one could use a `TT[]`, but `CreateInstance` won't care about the type of the array.  If `T` has a constructor which takes an `Interface1` and another which takes an `Interface2`, and the passed in object instance implements both interfaces, the `CreateInstance` call will fail due to ambiguity even if the passed in array is an `Interface1[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Activator<T>.CreateInstance()` overload you're trying to call expects a second argument of type `Object[]`.  The new array you are creating is a `TT[]`.  If `TT` were constrained to a class type, then a `TT[]` might satisfy the `Object[]` parameter.  An unconstrained generic `TT[]`, however, cannot be used as an `Object[]`.  Once the compiler determines that the `TT[]` cannot be passed as an `Object[]`, it then (because of the `params` specification on the second parameter of the overload), it checks whether the second parameter you're passing qualifies as an `Object`.  Because all arrays derive from `Object`, it will.  The compiler will thus create a single-element array of type `Object` which holds the `TT[]` that you were trying to pass in.  Since there is no constructor that expects an `Object[]`, the call will fail.

If you want to prevent this problem, create a new `Object[]` containing the appropriate parameters, instead of creating a new `TT[]`.  That should solve your problem.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the detailed explanation. O.R. Mapper did also mention to use object[]. Silly me! I was looking in the wrong direction.

Answer (score -1):

Change the constructor of class B as shown below:

```
public B(object someValue)
    {
        var myValue = someValue;
    }
```

and your code will start working properly.

Comment: Isn't that bad? I am trying to be more restrictive in my approach and be more typesafe instead of opening up for everything. Please I welcome any opinion on my concern.